# Spark Timeout Error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I'm getting this error during execution. Would appreciate any help.

```
`Launching sbt from sbt/sbt-launch-0.13.1.jar
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=350m; support was removed in 8.0
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/ahsansaeed/bd4h/final_proj/code/project
[info] Set current project to 8803_project_icu (in build file:/Users/ahsansaeed/bd4h/final_proj/code/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Users/ahsansaeed/bd4h/final_proj/code/target/scala-2.10/classes...
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Nov 18, 2016 3:35:40 AM
[info] Running edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main 
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
16/11/18 03:35:41 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
16/11/18 03:35:43 INFO Remoting: Starting remoting
16/11/18 03:35:43 INFO Remoting: Remoting started; listening on addresses :[akka.tcp://sparkDriverActorSystem@192.168.100.2:65107]
[Stage 30:=>                                                      (5 + 3) / 200]16/11/18 03:37:59 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread driver-heartbeater
java.io.IOException: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1207)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics.readObject(TaskMetrics.scala:219)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor26.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1058)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1909)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deserialize(Utils.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:437)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Executor.scala:427)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1.apply(Executor.scala:427)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat$1.apply(Executor.scala:425)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1157)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor.org$apache$spark$executor$Executor$$reportHeartBeat(Executor.scala:425)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Executor.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Executor.scala:470)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1765)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$$anon$1.run(Executor.scala:470)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2024)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadObject(ObjectInputStream.java:503)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics$$anonfun$readObject$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskMetrics.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1204)
    ... 32 more
[Stage 40:================>                                      (59 + 3) / 200]16/11/18 03:40:44 WARN HeartbeatReceiver: Removing executor driver with no recent heartbeats: 174473 ms exceeds timeout 120000 ms
16/11/18 03:40:44 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor driver on localhost: Executor heartbeat timed out after 174473 ms
16/11/18 03:40:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 60.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 908, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 174473 ms
16/11/18 03:40:44 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 60 in stage 40.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/11/18 03:40:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 59.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 907, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 174473 ms
16/11/18 03:40:44 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 61.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 909, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 174473 ms
[Stage 40:===============>                                     (59 + -57) / 200]16/11/18 03:40:44 WARN SparkContext: Killing executors is only supported in coarse-grained mode
[error] (run-main-0) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 60 in stage 40.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 60.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 908, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 174473 ms
[error] Driver stacktrace:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 60 in stage 40.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 60.0 in stage 40.0 (TID 908, localhost): ExecutorLostFailure (executor driver exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 174473 ms
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1952)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$reduce$1.apply(RDD.scala:1025)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.reduce(RDD.scala:1007)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$treeAggregate$1.apply(RDD.scala:1150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.treeAggregate(RDD.scala:1127)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.IDF.fit(IDF.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IDF.fit(IDF.scala:82)
    at edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main$.loadRddRawData(Main.scala:189)
    at edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main$.main(Main.scala:37)
    at edu.gatech.cse8803.main.Main.main(Main.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
16/11/18 03:40:44 ERROR Utils: uncaught error in thread SparkListenerBus, stopping SparkContext
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
    at java.util.concurrent.Semaphore.acquire(Semaphore.java:312)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:65)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1180)
    at org.apache.spark.util.AsynchronousListenerBus$$anon$1.run(AsynchronousListenerBus.scala:63)
16/11/18 03:40:44 ERROR ContextCleaner: Error in cleaning thread
java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:143)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning$1.apply$mcV$sp(ContextCleaner.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrStopSparkContext(Utils.scala:1180)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner.org$apache$spark$ContextCleaner$$keepCleaning(ContextCleaner.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.ContextCleaner$$anon$3.run(ContextCleaner.scala:68)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
[error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
[error] Total time: 304 s, completed Nov 18, 2016 3:40:44 AM`
```

I am setting following parameters, but is there some timeout param that I could set?

```
val conf = new SparkConf()
  .setAppName(appName)
  .setMaster(masterUrl)
  .set("spark.executor.memory", "6g")
  .set("spark.driver.memory", "6g")
  .set("spark.executor.heartbeatinterval", "10000000")
  .set("spark.driver.heartbeatinverval", "10000000")
new SparkContext(conf)
```

I am using `sbt/sbt compile run` to compile and run the project. I have looked for the posts concerning this issue and tried to make above modifications -- I was running only with `setAppName & setMaster` initially.

I am using `scalaVersion = 2.10.5 & spark = 1.6.1`. I am running on `local` single cluster.

My machine configurations are: `Macbook Pro,i5, 16G RAM`

I'd be glad to provide any information that might give more insight into the issue.

Note : Code is present [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/111d783e167a79ebb2967edae5a6fa45)

Comment: There seems to be someother problem ,can you please paste your driver stacktrace !

Comment: can you once check on spark ui at localhost:4040 because 175772 ms is less than 10000000 so its look like conf is not set properly

Comment: You need to check the logs of your executor and see why they are crashing.

Comment: I have updated the error with complete stack trace. I am new to spark,  and @SandeepPurohit I think you are suggesting this URL to be opened from the browser t check configs? When I run `localhot:4040` I don't see any page.

Comment: check you configurations here http://localhost:4040/environment/

Comment: Opening this URL in chrome gives me `localhost refuse to connect`

Comment: aaah according to stack trace its not looks like configuration problem see the cause Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics._accumulatorUpdates of type scala.collection.immutable.Map in instance of org.apache.spark.executor.TaskMetrics
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)

Comment: @Ahsan can you share code ??

Comment: Sure... working to get it. Do I need to edit my original post?

Comment: @Ahsan yes just paste the link here and upload it as a gist on your github !

Comment: here it is: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/111d783e167a79ebb2967edae5a6fa45

Comment: I am loading a csv file, and then fetching data from it. File is around 4GB in size. Not sure how I can upload that.

Comment: @Ahsan are you using spark 2.0??

Comment: No, I am using Spark 1.6.1

Comment: I am thinking perhaps problem is in spark while parsing the csv file?